# Unable to change values within a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im currently working with the alt:v gta multiplayer. I want to load a angular page in the game by using a webview.

The problem I have is that a method is invoked which I fetch in a component but the variables I change in the callback don't change it on the html.

```js
declare var alt:any;

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = '';
  isOpen = false;


  ngOnInit() {
    //eventHandler from alt:v
    alt.on("eventName", (msg) => {
        this.title = msg;
        this.isOpen = true;
    }
  }
```

If I log my changes to the variables it says that the got changed but the html page shows still the old values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is updated but you need to force Angular to detect your changes via `ChangeDetectorRef` because `alt.on("eventName")` is called outside of the Angular Zone reference [here.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) and using this service will force Angular to detect any changes of your component and re-render your view.

Example:

```
declare var alt:any;

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = '';
  isOpen = false;

  constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //eventHandler from alt:v
    alt.on("eventName", (msg) => {
        this.title = msg;
        this.isOpen = true;
        this.changeRef.detectChanges(); // force to detect changes and render you view again
    }
  }
```

Comment: awesome man :) working as expected now! totally forgot about it.